# Assign values from small matrix to specified places in larger matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to know if there exists a similar way of doing this (Mathematica) in Python:
[Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk3wS.png)

I have tried it in Python and it does not work. I have also tried it with `numpy.put()` or with simple 2 `for` loops. This 2 ways work properly but I find them very time consuming with larger matrices (3000×3000 elements for example).

Described problem in Python,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0, 25, 1).reshape(5, 5)
b = np.arange(100, 500, 100).reshape(2, 2)
p = np.array([0, 3])

a[p][:, p] = b
```

which outputs non-changed matrix `a`: [Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9IYR.png)

Comment: how is p mapped onto a.  I see the values for p as 0, 3  What is the mathematical syntax telling me.   I see the values 100 and 200 map to a position 0 and 3.  How are positions for 300 and 400 determined?

Comment: In the above code, `a[p][:, p]` gives a slice of matrix `a`, similary as `a[0:2, 0:2]`, but in a more general way (rows and columns can be skipped, with `:` the whole range is taken). However, in the first case values of matrix `a` are not replaced, but if we use the second approach they are.

Comment: In your example, with `p = [0,3]`, could you please post the exact expected output (the exact modified array `a`)?

Comment: My desired output:
`[[100, 1, 2, 200, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [300, 16, 17, 400, 19], 
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]`

Comment: Please check my edited answer. I think it produces the same output as in your external linked image.

Comment: How does 0 and 3 create the 300 and 400 substitution?  I see how it could do the 100 and 200.  I don't understand the equation.  A is a 5 x 5 matrix or a 2 array.  B is 4 number 1 d array.  P is two numbers 0 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
a[p[...,None], p] = b
```

**Array `a` after the above assignment looks like this:**

```
[[100   1   2 200   4]
 [  5   6   7   8   9]
 [ 10  11  12  13  14]
 [300  16  17 400  19]
 [ 20  21  22  23  24]]
```

As documented in [Integer Array Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), the two integer index arrays will be broadcasted together, and iterated together, which effectively indexes the locations `a[0,0]`, `a[0,3]`, `a[3,0]`, and `a[3,3]`. The assignment statement would then perform an element-wise assignment at these locations of `a`, using the respective element-values from RHS.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that is not what I was looking for. Maybe the question is now better defined (random -> specified). With ''random'' I meaned that the places are specified not in a particular order or pattern, but they are defined by the user.

Comment: @t616 -- Ok, but still some things are not clear about your requirement. For example, will  `p` always have a shape of `(2,)`, as in your example? Why does `p` have only two indices, while `b` (the source of the assignment) has `4` values? And how are those indices in `p` to be applied (that is, along which axis of `a` must those indices be applied?). Please provide a more exhaustive description of your requirement.

Comment: Your output is really close, except 200 and 300 should be switched.

Comment: @t616 -- Ok, I've edited to switch the `200` and `300`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `a[p[...,None], p] = b` is correct.

Comment: mat3=mat1[p[...,None], p] = mat2
print(mat3)  does not produce the desired output. see my results below.

Comment: @GoldenLion - Pls elaborate how my output doesn't match the desired output. And btw, OP has confirmed (in the comments above, as well as by Accepting my answer) that my answer's output matches the desired output.

Comment: it produced the output:[[100,200],[300,400]].   Not the desired output as specified above

Comment: the desired output was: [[100, 1, 2, 200, 4],  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],  [300, 16, 17, 400, 19],   [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]

Comment: @GoldenLion - The assignment statement mentioned in my answer affects exactly `4` specified locations in the original array `a`. I suggest that you try the assignment statement mentioned in my answer, and then print the value of `a`. It will then produce the desired output. I have checked again and it works exactly as asked for.

Comment: @GoldenLion - My guess is that, instead of printing the original array `a` after my assignment statement, you probably printed only the LHS of my assignment statement (`a[p[...,None], p]`). That is probably why you wrongly thought that it was producing the wrong output of `[[100,200],[300,400]]` I suggest that you read OP's question once more.

Comment: mat1[p[...,None], p] = mat2
print(mat1) -  I agree.  Explain what this syntax is doing.  you will need to get my vote changed by editing it.